# 2-opt algorithm using generators instead for nested for loop

Tags: python-3.x, nested, generator, traveling-salesman

I am using an opt-2 approach on the TSP problem and have adapted some code I found on-line. I pass in a list road_map which is a list of tuples that contains a region (string), city (string), latitude (float) and longitude (float) like the following (lats and longs made up here)

```
[('South England' 'London', '32.361538', '-86.279118'), 
 ('Yorkshire', 'Manchester', 35,6656, '-86.4543')]
```

I want to use this 2-opt algorithm to reorder the map and return a new map/route that contains a shorter distance than the previous one, this will be the best_map.

Below are my two functions I am using but it seems messy with the while nested fors and if statements. I think there must be a much cleaner way of doing this with generator functions, but I am unable to think how. Any ideas?

```
def opt2(best_map, i, j):

   new_map = best_map[:]
   new_map[i:j] = best_map[j:i:-1]

   return new_map


def start_opt2(road_map):

   best_map = road_map[:]
   best_distance = compute_total_distance(best_map)

   for i in range(len(best_map) + 1):
       for j in range(i+1, len(best_map)):
          new_map = opt2(best_map, i, j)
          new_distance = compute_total_distance(new_map)

          if new_distance < best_distance:
               best_distance= new_distance
               best_map = new_map
               break


return best_map
```

Comment: This might be a good question for [codereview.se]; for SO it may be a bit too broad.

Comment: Why does the `j` range stop lower than the `i` range?